# Why is an alternating multilinear map called "alternating"?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, multilinear-algebra

I know it's just a small detail, but it's kind of bothering me... A multilinear map is called "alternating" if having two equal arguments makes it zero.

Why use the word "alternating" then? What precisely is alternating?

Comment: I always guessed it's because interchanging two of the inputs flips the sign of the output. So the sign of the output "alternates".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, if the characteristic of the coefficient field is different from $2$, then the following statements are equivalent:

- $f(x, y, \dots) = -f(y, x, \dots)$ for any $x, y$;
- $f(x, x, \dots) = 0$ for any $x$.

The proof is an easy exercise.

In your question, you take the second statement as definition. But the first one is more suitable for the name "alternating".

Comment: And once again, we see an example of how characteristic 2 behaves strangely. As I always say, 2 is the oddest prime ;)

Comment: Although this answer is true, it doesn't seem to explain what exactly does "alternate" here.

Comment: @lisyarus The alternating group acts trivially on it: $f(x_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(n)}) = f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ if and only if $\sigma$ belongs to $A_n$, the alternating group.

Comment: Makes sense! Since it's a *multilinear* map, fixing one of two arguments and varying the other, if it's also alternating (as per the second statement), implies the change in sign.

Answer (score 1):

A $k$-Tensor $\omega\in\mathcal{T}^{k}(V)$ is called alternating if
$$\omega(v_{1},\cdots ,v_i,\cdots v_j,\cdots, v_n)=-\omega(v_{1},\cdots ,v_j,\cdots v_i,\cdots, v_n)$$
for $v_1,\cdots v_{n} \quad in \quad V$.

As such, that is the definition that it is altered that the multilinear application changed the position coordinates and fixed the rest